# In between the calendar div and the external events fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

Can anybody tell me which fullcalendar event callback should I use 
To handle the case where : **the current external event  stopped dragging 
  and it's localised not over the external events Box neither over The Calendar**?

knowing that I have both methods isEventOverDiv 
//return true/false if we are (not) over the external events and isEventOverDivCal//return true/false if we are (not) over the calendar

I tried in eventDragStop: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view)

```
  eventDragStop: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view){

    // if the event is not over the external events box and neither over the calendar
    if(!isEventOverDiv(jsEvent.clientX, jsEvent.clientY) && !isEventOverDivCal(jsEvent.clientX, jsEvent.clientY) ) {
        // reset 
         var reccupuredIndexForTitle=$(this).attr('id');
         $scope.ctrlendDragging(reccupuredIndexForTitle);
    }

    }



    //return true if we are over the external events
    var isEventOverDiv = function (x, y) {

        var external_events = $('#external-events');
        var offset = external_events.offset();
        offset.right = external_events.width() + offset.left;
        offset.bottom = external_events.height() + offset.top;

        // Compare
        if (x >= offset.left &&
        y >= offset.top &&
        x <= offset.right &&
        y <= offset.bottom) {return true;}
        return false;

    };

    //return true if we are over the calendar
    var isEventOverDivCal = function(x, y) {
                var external_events = $( '#calendar' );
                var offset = external_events.offset();
                offset.right = external_events.width() + offset.left;
                offset.bottom = external_events.height() + offset.top;

                // Compare
                if (x >= offset.left
                    && y >= offset.top
                    && x <= offset.right
                    && y <= offset .bottom) { return true;}
                return false;
    }
```

**but it's not working.**

## update 2

in order to overcome the obstacle of putting events above the virtual scroll bar during their trip into the calendar

1- I apply from mycontroller **$scope.ctrlstartDragging** 
   (which triggers from the HTML view on **ondragstart="angular.element(this).scope().ctrlstartDragging(id)"** callback).

```
$scope.ctrlstartDragging = function(id) {

        var book = document.getElementById(id);
        var domRect = absolutePosition(book);
            book.style.position = 'fixed';
            book.style.top = domRect.top + 'px';
            book.style.left = domRect.left + 'px';
            book.style.width=(domRect.width) + 'px';

    };
```

and to be able to unset css styles (position top left width)

(N.B:  **ondragend="angular.element(this).scope().ctrlendDragging(id)"** callback)

is not fired and I don't know why but it's not a problematic in my case)

so the purpose is that I should call manually

```
$scope.ctrlendDragging = function(id) {

   var book = document.getElementById(id);
        book.style.position = 'relative';
        book.style.top = 'unset';
        book.style.left = 'unset';
        book.style.width='unset';
};
```

and to do as I said, in case the user aborts to put the event on the calendar during the dragging and this event is positioned both outside the external event box and outside the calendar.

but in my case see [MyPlunk](https://codepen.io/adier/pen/zewGgv)  I need when the revert is applied , I will need during the revert of this event to the external event box to do make a call to it with the folloiwing

```
 // reset 
 var reccupuredIndexForTitle=$(this).attr('id');
 $scope.ctrlendDragging(reccupuredIndexForTitle);
```

so I need when the revert is applied I sould apply those two lines
 because if they are not applied when an user abort a dragging into the calendar 
 the event revert but without the unset css styles applied to .style.position top left width
 I would get an one isolated external event on the top of the external events box like shown below:

[image]

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is any specific method you can use to detect such a thing. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventReceive will detect when an external event is dragged onto the calendar. As far as I know, if the user drags and external event onto an area which is not the calendar, then no fullCalendar callback will run - because fullCalendar hasn't detected anything happening to itself, and so doesn't care about that event. And surely if the user does that, it's meaningless, they just made a mistake? The whole point of the feature is to allow users to drag things onto the calendar.

Comment: many thanks ADyson for your answer. I updated see update for more info.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something important in what you're saying, but you seem to be making it very complicated. I found a CodePen which seems to have some similar code to yours, but also seems to do all the things you need - events can be dragged onto the calendar, and also dragged back to the "external events" list again. If the event is dropped anywhere outside those two areas, it goes back to where it started. See it here: https://codepen.io/subodhghulaxe/pen/qEXLLr . Is there still something else missing from that demo which you need to be able to do?

Comment: thanks again ADyson see update 2. to see clearly where exactely  having the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added the following to my controller:

```
    var x =-1;
    var y=-1;
    $('#external-events').on('dragstop', function(evt) 
    {

            isDragging = false;
            x = evt.originalEvent.pageX;
            y = evt.originalEvent.pageY;
            if(!isDragging && x !=-1 && y!=-1 && !isEventOverDiv(x, y) && !isEventOverDivCal(x, y) )               
            {
                     // reset 
                     var reccupuredIndexForTitle=$('.fc-event').attr('id');
                     $scope.ctrlendDragging(reccupuredIndexForTitle);
            }

    });
```

As you can see from the code, I used jquery **on('dragstop')** because I don't know why 
on ondragend event is not fired

so I removed it from my view HTML **ondragend="angular.element(this).scope().ctrlendDragging(id)"**

and called manualy from my controller **$scope.ctrlendDragging(id)** to reset the current dragged event when stoped via $('#external-events').on('dragstop', function(evt)
and handled the case the current external event stopped dragging and it's localised not over the external events Box neither over The Calendar
via

```
if(!isDragging && x !=-1 && y!=-1 && !isEventOverDiv(x, y) && !isEventOverDivCal(x, y) )
```

[Working codePen](https://codepen.io/adier/pen/pGdJeE)

### update2:

Because The first solution is basic and work in hazardous conditions 
   It works only for the first draggable li 
   and it's not exact nor precise. I made an update to the following:

```
    var domRect;
    var isDragging = false;
    var x =-1;
    var y=-1;
    $scope.positionX =-1;
    $scope.positionY=-1;    

    var myId=-1;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $scope.ctrlstartDragging = function(id) {
               myId = id;
        };


        $scope.ctrlendDragging = function(id) {

           book.style.zIndex = "9999";

        };  




        $('#external-events').on('dragstop', function(evt)
        {  

           $scope.$watchGroup(['positionX','positionY'],function () {
                  x = $scope.positionX;
                  y = $scope.positionY;

           });

           if(!isDragging && x !=-1 && y!=-1 && !isEventOverDiv(x, y) && !isEventOverDivCal(x, y) )      {
                         // reset 
                         var reccupuredIndexForTitle=myId;
                         $scope.ctrlendDragging(reccupuredIndexForTitle);
           } 

        });

});//end of $(document).ready(function()
```

Enclosed in **$(document).ready(function() {** 
all functions that shoul be  appplied in document ready:

1- **$scope.ctrlstartDragging** from which we get myId equal (current li) id passed
via html view **ondragstart="angular.element(this).scope().ctrlstartDragging(id)"**

2- **$scope.ctrlendDragging**  n.b : I set the z-index via 
   **book.style.zIndex = "9999";** so we could work in a modal context

3- **$('#external-events').on('dragstop', function(evt)** that should work in 
   **$(document).ready(function() {** or **$window.load** 
   where added a watchgroup on changes made on positionX positionY of an li

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['positionX','positionY'],function () {
                  x = $scope.positionX;
                  y = $scope.positionY;

});
```

also added

```
if(!isDragging && x !=-1 && y!=-1 && !isEventOverDiv(x, y) && !isEventOverDivCal(x, y) )      {
                                 // reset 
                                 var reccupuredIndexForTitle=myId;
                                 $scope.ctrlendDragging(reccupuredIndexForTitle);
               }
```

which work with myId this time gotten from **$scope.ctrlstartDragging**

**On the other Hand,** I added when initialising external events

**$('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {**

**drag: function(){** to get the exact positionX positionY for the current dragged li element

```
$(this).draggable({
              zIndex: 999,
              revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
              revertDuration: 0,  //  original position after the drag
      drag: function(){
                  var offset = $(this).offset();
                  var xPos = offset.left;
                  var yPos = offset.top;

                  $scope.$apply(function() {

                    $scope.positionX =xPos;
                    $scope.positionY = yPos;

                  });

              }
});
```

[Working codePen for li](https://codepen.io/adier/pen/mvXrqW)

Hope it may help somebody ;).